# How to receive JSON from Api.ai

Tags: google-api, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have created a google assistant app, using actions on google api.ai
I created a Oauth2 server and account linking successfully. My app is now under review. But, im not sure how to pass the api.ai created json file to my server. 
In the fulfilment page i put the above url
https://myserver.com/recjson.php 
This is the recjson.php file

```
<?php
$jsonString =   file_get_contents("php://input");
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
file_put_contents($myFile$jsonString);
echo '{ "success": true }';
?>
```

Comment: You will get the API.AI JSON file to your end-point (e.g. the url you filled in the fulfilment page). If you want to make sure - log the output. Btw, you have an error in your code at file_put_contents($myFile$jsonString); It should be file_put_contents($myFile , $jsonString);